# What should I do when I find a bug in a feature branch that I'm currently working on?

Tags: git, github

Sometimes when I branch out from master to work on a new feature branch, in the middle of my work I notice that there is a bug that needs to be fixed. Let's say that I'm working on 'feature_chat' branch and I notice a bug. Should I commit my changes and open a new 'fix' branch or should I fix the bug in the current branch? What is the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: I think this depends a lot on your release cadence and process etc. etc. but as a general rule, if the bug is related to your new feature work, you fix it in your feature branch, but if it's unrelated, you open a separate bugfix ticket off of master and fix the bug there.  Then they are not coupled (if the feature gets delayed/canceled/deprioritized, you still get the fix in as a separate piece of work.)

Answer (score 1):

I would test and review the bug on separate branch. especially when i use `fix/` `feature/` annotations at the end it depends on you, your team, how you relating to the branches and what the scenario you fall in

**Scenario 1** bug and feature are not related

Create a new branch `fix/[disc_bug]` beside `feature/[disc_feature]`.
then open pull request for both branches.

your bug fix may be merged in short time to the master but your feature branch may need a lot of refactoring and changes and it will be merged after some time.

**Scenario 2** bug blocks feature

One way to do this is by checkout the `fix/[disc_bug]` from `master`. merge `feature/[disc_feature]` with `fix/[disc_bug]`,

PR the fix branch and continue your work while you are waiting it to be merged. when the fix branch reviewed and merged(maybe with some changes) you can update the feature branch with the master again.

you could also PR both but require to merge bug branch before the feature.

**Scenario 3** bug **only** relates to your feature

If the bug affect only the feature you want to add. in this case i would consider fixing the bug in a commit inside the feature branch. and it will be reviewed together with the feature.

but i still prefer separated branches. one reason could be is what if you revert the feature in the future. reverting features should not re-create bugs that others may face them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a very small thing that has been lurking there for a long time and no one has ever noticed it, I think it is ok to just fix it right there. On the other hand, if it's a big thing, I would stash what I have in front of me and would correct the bug on a separate branch.